# How can I prevent VBA code, used to draw up a list of unique words from a word document, from slowing down as the document get's longer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have used some code from the internet, modified slightly for my specific use case, to draw up a list of unique words from a word document, the code works without a problem, but the time to execute the code seems to grow exponentially as the document length increases. Can anyone give me any suggestions to speed up the code when working with very long documents?

```
    Sub UniqueWordList()
    Dim wList As New Collection
    Dim wrd
    Dim chkwrd
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim k As Long
    Dim cWrd As Long
    Dim tWrd As Long
    Dim nWrd As String
    Dim Flag As Boolean
    
    Flag = False
    tWrd = ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count
    cWrd = 0

    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words
    
        cWrd = cWrd + 1
        
        If cWrd Mod 100 = 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Updating: " & (cWrd)
        End If
    
        If Flag Then
            Flag = False
            GoTo nw
        End If
        
        If cWrd < tWrd Then
            nWrd = ActiveDocument.Words(cWrd + 1)
            nWrd = Trim(LCase(nWrd))
        End If
        
        sTemp = Trim(LCase(wrd))
                     
        If sTemp = "‘" Then
            sTemp = sTemp & nWrd
            Flag = True
        End If

        If sTemp Like "*[a-zA-Z]*" Then

            k = 0
            For Each chkwrd In wList
                k = k + 1
                If chkwrd = sTemp Then GoTo nw
                If chkwrd > sTemp Then
                    wList.Add Item:=sTemp, Before:=k
                    GoTo nw
                End If
            Next chkwrd
            wList.Add Item:=sTemp
        End If
nw:
    Next wrd

    sTemp = "There are " & ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count & " words "
    sTemp = sTemp & "in the document, before this summary, but there "
    sTemp = sTemp & "are only " & wList.Count & " unique words."

    ActiveDocument.Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf & sTemp & vbCrLf
    For Each chkwrd In wList
        Selection.TypeText chkwrd & vbCrLf
    Next chkwrd
    

    
End Sub
```

After some suggestions I modified my code to use a scripting dictionary, this however does not seem to have solved the problem. Also to answer the concern regarding my message at the end, I understand that the wording is off, what I want is a list of words from the document but each word only once.

```
Sub UniqueWordListMi()
    Dim wList() As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim cWrd As Long
    Dim tWrd As Long
    Dim nWrd As String
    Dim Flag As Boolean
    Dim IsInArray As Boolean
    Dim arrsize As Long
    Dim rra2 As Variant
    
    arrsize = 0
    Flag = False
    tWrd = ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count
    cWrd = 1

ReDim Preserve wList(0 To arrsize)
wList(arrsize) = "UNQ"
        
For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words

If cWrd Mod 100 = 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Updating" & (cWrd)
    End If
    
If Flag Then
            Flag = False
            GoTo nw
        End If
        
        If cWrd < tWrd Then
            nWrd = ActiveDocument.Words(cWrd + 1)
            nWrd = Trim(LCase(nWrd))
            
        End If
        
        sTemp = Trim(LCase(wrd))
        
        
        If sTemp = "‘" Then
            sTemp = sTemp & nWrd
            Flag = True
        End If
        
        If sTemp Like "*[a-zA-Z]*" Then
            ReDim Preserve wList(0 To arrsize)
            wList(arrsize) = sTemp
            arrsize = arrsize + 1
        End If
nw:
cWrd = cWrd + 1
Next wrd

Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For i = 0 To UBound(wList)
    If (Not Dict.Exists(CStr(wList(i)))) Then Dict.Add CStr(wList(i)), wList(i) 'Next i
Next i

rra2 = Dict.Items

sTemp = "There are " & ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count & " words "
    sTemp = sTemp & "in the document, before this summary, but there "
    sTemp = sTemp & "are only " & UBound(wList) & " unique words."

    ActiveDocument.Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf & sTemp & vbCrLf
     
For u = 0 To UBound(rra2)
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf & rra2(u) & vbCrLf
    Next u
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider creating a `Scripting.Dictionary` and using `.Exists()` to see if you have already added the candidate word. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)

Comment: Note that your code does not what your message tells. If I write `Test Test Test` in an empty Word document and run your code I get *"There are 5 words in the document, before this summary, but there are only 1 unique words."* Which is wrong. There are only 3 words and actually none of them is unique! What your code does is removing duplicate words from a list of words, but that is not finding unique words. Unique words are words that occur only once in a text. Example: *"This is an example test where every word is unique except one"*. Your code will include *"is"* but it is not unique.

Comment: So either you mean distinct words (that is what your list represents) or unique words (a list of words that occur only once in a text). Can you clarify what exactly of these 2 your goal is? • *"This is an example test where every word is unique except one"* = 12 words, 10 unique words (all except "is") but 11 distinct words.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to include an approach using Scripting.Dictionary, unfortunately this did not resolve the slow down.

Comment: @NcBean instead of going through an array `ReDim Preserve wList(0 To arrsize)` use the dictionary for `wList` directly. Check if the word exists in the dictionary `Dict.Exists` and if not add it. This way you will get a dictionary containing all words once. No need of an array here. • Note that this will only improve your code. But still the longer the document will get the more words need to be checked and the more time it will need. That fact will not change, you can just optimize it by using the dictionary directly.

Comment: Note that in Word vba, punctuation is counted as a word. So is a paragraph break, a line break, and a page break. If, with a copy of your document, you could replace those out of the document, it could speed up your code. -- Another possibility would be to replace all instance of a word, once found, with nothing. Again, in a copy of your document!

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/31360-post2.html. The code there outputs a list of all words in the document, including their frequency and page #s. If you really want only the unique words, a few more lines of code could be added to exclude all counts greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexK beat me to it with a comment on using a  Scripting.Dictionary.

Something like this might help

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CountUniqueWords(ByRef ipRange As Word.Range) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim myUniqueWords As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myUniqueWords = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim myPara As Variant
    
    For Each myPara In ipRange.Paragraphs
    
        Dim myWord As Variant
        For Each myWord In Split(myPara.Range.Text)
        
            If myUniqueWords.Exists(myWord) Then
            
                myUniqueWords.Item(myWord) = myUniqueWords.Item(myWord) + 1
                
            Else
            
                myUniqueWords.Add myWord, 1
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    Set CountUniqueWords = myUniqueWords
    
End Function
```

Some polishing might be required to meet your specific requirements.

You can't help some increase in processing time as the document gets longer but as the access to the document is limited to paragraphs rather than words is should proceed somewhat faster.

Comment: While this kind of solution will give you a list of words **without duplicates** this gives not a list of **unique** words. Unique words are words that occur only once in a text. Example: "This is an example test where every word is unique except one". Your code will list *"is"* as a unique word while it is clearly not, it is occuring twice, therefore cannot be unique. What your code does is removing duplicates, but that is something different.

Comment: PEH you are quite right my wording is off, I want a list of all words in the document but listing each word only once.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to include an approach using Scripting.Dictionary, unfortunately this did not resolve the slow down.

Comment: @PEH The scripting dictionary gives you a count of each word.  The next step would be to iterate through the dictionary and remove any items with a count greater than 1 (or compile a second dictionary where the item count is only 1.  Additionally, please note I said my code might help and that some polishing may be required.

Comment: @freeflow I was aware of that ^^ What I wanted to point out is, there is a difference in *"unique"* words and *"distinct"* words, so either the wording here is wrong or the code does not what the function is named `CountUniqueWords` because it counts distinct words. I was just trying to show up this confusion about what the code actually does and what it pretends to do by its naming.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It uses the dictionary directly with the rules of your code.

Note that this will only improve your code. But still, the longer the document will get, the more words need to be checked and the more time it will need. That fact will not change, you can just optimize it by using the dictionary directly but more words need more time to check.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueWordListMi()
    Dim wList As Object
    Set wList = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim cWrd As Long
    Dim tWrd As Long
    Dim nWrd As String
    Dim Flag As Boolean
    Dim IsInArray As Boolean
    Dim arrsize As Long
    Dim rra2 As Variant
    
    arrsize = 0
    Flag = False
    tWrd = ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count
    cWrd = 1

    Dim wrd As Variant
    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words    
        If cWrd Mod 100 = 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Updating" & (cWrd)
        End If
    
        If Flag Then
            Flag = False
            GoTo nw
        End If
        
        If cWrd < tWrd Then
            nWrd = ActiveDocument.Words(cWrd + 1)
            nWrd = Trim(LCase(nWrd))
        End If
        
        sTemp = Trim(LCase(wrd))
        If sTemp = "‘" Then
            sTemp = sTemp & nWrd
            Flag = True
        End If
        
        If sTemp Like "*[a-zA-Z]*" Then
            If Not wList.Exists(sTemp) Then
                wList.Add sTemp, 1
            Else
                wList.Item(sTemp) = wList.Item(sTemp) + 1
            End If
            cWrd = cWrd + 1
        End If
nw:
    Next wrd

    sTemp = "There are " & (cWrd - 1) & " words "
    sTemp = sTemp & "in the document, before this summary, but there "
    sTemp = sTemp & "are only " & wList.Count & " distinct words."

    ActiveDocument.Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf & sTemp & vbCrLf
    
    Dim chkwrd As Variant
    For Each chkwrd In wList
        Selection.TypeText chkwrd & vbTab & wList.Item(chkwrd) & " times" & vbCrLf
    Next chkwrd   
End Sub
```

The following example:

> ```
> This is an example test where every word is unique except one.
>
> There are 12 words in the document, before this summary, but there are only 11 distinct words.
> this      1 times
> is        2 times
> an        1 times
> example   1 times
> test      1 times
> where     1 times
> every     1 times
> word      1 times
> unique    1 times
> except    1 times
> one       1 times
> ```

Answer (score 0):

With everyone's help and some additional reading, as well as some help from a reddit user this code work's perfectly:

```
Sub UniqueWordListFast()
    Dim WordDictionary As Object
    Dim SourceText As Document
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim sTemp As String, strWord As String, nxtWord As String
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0

    Set WordDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set SourceText = Application.ActiveDocument

    For Each objWord In SourceText.Range.Words
        count = count + 1
        strWord = Trim(objWord.Text)
        If strWord = nxtWord Then GoTo nw
        If strWord Like "*[a-z]*" Then WordDictionary(strWord) = strWord
        If strWord Like "‘" Then
            nxtWord = Trim(SourceText.Words(count + 1))
            strWord = strWord & nxtWord
            WordDictionary(strWord) = strWord
        End If
nw:
    Next

    sTemp = "[DOCUMENT] " & vbTab & SourceText.Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "There are " & SourceText.Range.Words.count & " words in the document, " & _
    "before this summary, but there are only " & WordDictionary.count & " unique words."

    Dim NewDocument As Document
    Set NewDocument = Documents.Add
    NewDocument.Range.Text = sTemp & vbCrLf & Join(WordDictionary.Keys, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Extremely fast and efficient. Thank you everyone!